# Инверсия над строкой в Java

Tags: java, символы

java позволяет рисовать одиночные макроны, т.е `String s = "a\u0305c\u0305"`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо сделать инверсию (по сути - прорисовать линию) над строкой, содержащей в себе другие макроны

например: [image: строка с иверсией]

как это сделать, если при `"a\u0305\u0305"` они просто стакаются?

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, что значит «стакаются». [в русском языке есть такое устаревшее (или разг.-сниж.) слово](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/249629), но его значение явно не может относиться ни к программированию вообще, ни к символам в частности.

Comment: накладываются друг на друга, и на выводе разница между "a\u0305" и "a\u0305\u0305" - такая, что во втором случае макрон над символом будет темнее ( в Idea ). Мне же нужно, чтобы рисовало их обоих, друг над другом

Comment: А чем рисуется текст? И где?

Comment: Не рисуется, это я образно сказал. Вывод в файл

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так

```
System.out.println("1"+ "\u0305");
```

Только "устройство вывода" должно понимать unicode

Вот полезных ссылкок

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline

http://graphemica.com/0305

Или вопрос был про другое?

Comment: а больше 1 линии можно так вывести?

Comment: насколько я понял, это больше зависит от среды, которая будет эту строку отрисовывать. Java может послать на stdout любой набор символов, а уж как этот stdout ими распорядится - это уже его дело. Например вот это, в идеальном случае, должно дать два надчеркивания System.out.println("1" + "\u0305" + "\u0305");

Comment: @rjhdby должно, но, в idea (как и в eclipse) они попросту накладываются друг на друга